# Trying to call a helper module in schedule.rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In scheduler.rake I have this method:

```
task :email_unaccepted_meetings => :environment do
  desc "If meeting time is less than 3 days away, and not accepted, send email to requestee"
  @date_plus_three_days = Time.now + 3.days
  @meetings = Meeting.where("status = ? AND accepted != ? AND meeting_time < ? ", "Active", true, @date_plus_three_days)
    if @meetings != nil
      @meetings.each do |meeting|
        EmailAndPushHelper.unaccepted_lex_request(meeting.id)
      end
    end
end
```

and in `/controllers/concerns/email_and_push_helper.rb` I have this:

```
module EmailAndPushHelper
  def unaccepted_lex_request(meeting_id)
    puts meeting_id
    @meeting = Meeting.find(meeting_id)
    if(check_settings(@meeting.requestee_id, 'lex_email') == true)
      MeetingMailer.unaccepted_mtg_request(@meeting).deliver_later
    end

    if(check_settings(@meeting.requestee_id, 'lex_push'))
      @title = "A Lex request needs your response."
      @message = "#{@meeting.requestor.preferred_name} is waiting for your response.'"
      @data  = {
        "status": "ok",
        "body": @message,
        "title": @title,
        "meetingId": @meeting.id
      }

      PushNotificationWorker.perform_async(@meeting.requestee.id, @title, @message, @data)
    end
  end
end
```

When I call the task `email_unaccepted_meetings` I get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'unaccepted_lex_request' for EmailAndPushHelper:Module)`

In other rake tasks I am calling Mailer methods, Worker methods, so I'm not totally understanding what is going on here. I've tried requiring the file in scheduler.rake but it gives the same error, which makes me believe that it's accessing the file `/controllers/concerns/email_and_push_helper.rb`, but can not find the method `unaccepted_lex_request` for some reason?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To declare module methods you need to define the method with `self`.

```
module EmailAndPushHelper
  def self.unaccepted_lex_request(meeting_id)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Instance methods of a module are only available when you include or extend something else with the module. Not as a method of the module itself.

But this really the wrong place/name for this code. `controller/concerns` is really where you put mixins that are mixed into your controller. Neither is this really a helper which is also an extremely vague term that also generally means a mixin thats used in the view and sometimes the controller in Rails.

This code actually belongs in a job or a service object.

```
class EmailAndPushJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(meeting)
    # You will have to solve the NoMethodError here
    if check_settings(meeting.requestee_id, 'lex_email')
      MeetingMailer.unaccepted_mtg_request(meeting).deliver_later
    end
    if check_settings(meeting.requestee_id, 'lex_push')
      title = "A Lex request needs your response."
      message = "#{meeting.requestor.preferred_name} is waiting for your response.'"
      PushNotificationWorker.perform_async(meeting.requestee.id, title, message, {
        # Use strings or symbols!
        "status" => "ok",
        "body" => message,
        "title" => title,
        "meetingId" => meeting.id
      })
    end
  end
end
```

You also want to use [batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) in your rake task instead of just `.each` as that will load every record into memory and crash your server once you have a decent amount of data.

```
task :email_unaccepted_meetings => :environment do
  desc "If meeting time is less than 3 days away, and not accepted, send email to requestee"
  meetings = Meeting.where(
     status: "Active", 
     accepted: true, 
     meeting_time: Time.now..3.days.from_now
  ).find_each do |meeting|
    EmailAndPushJob.perform_now(meeting)
  end
end
```

Comment: One a side note - you need to stop using `@instance` variables all over the place. If you are only using a variable in that method make it a local variable. If you misstype the name of a local variable you will get an error straight away that tells you about the misstake - an ivar will let it slip and cause a nil error down the line.

Comment: Also `{ "foo": 1 "bar": 2 }` should be avoided. It looks like a hash with string keys but actually creates a hash with symbol keys. Use `{ foo: 1 ...}` or `{ "foo" => 1 }` and be clear about what your intent is.

Comment: And to be clear - yes this code will fail with a NoMethodError since check_settings is not defined. Its meant as a starting point, not as a finished product.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding this to the top of scheduler.rake

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/concerns/email_and_push_helper.rb"
include EmailAndPushHelper
```

And calling it like this:

```
    `EmailAndPushHelper::unaccepted_lex_request(meeting.id)`
```

Comment: By "fixed" you really just mitigated the problem somewhat. You still can't just mix a controller concern into a rake task and think everything is going to be hunky dory. The context is completely different and you're just laying a trap for future you or whoever has to maintain this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it seems to be working fine though. I'm the only one working on this project and maintaining it - but what would be the repercussions of this method? I haven't experienced any issues yet. Also, I use the `EmailAndPushHelper` in controllers and workers, so I was having issues finding a good way to set this up so that it is accessible in a worker, controller, and in scheduler.rake, which is why I went with this structure, but happy to learn a better way!

Comment: Well if you're writing a controller mixin you will be tempted to use methods that are available in the controller like for example `request` but that will break your task. Thats why its better to write a service/job if you want to share code between a controller and task. That way you need to explicitly pass any context into it. Think of it as composing objects that do one job and do it well vs just copypasting code around.